# Import Mathmatical equation and image from docx file using PHP DOMDocument::loadXML

Tags: php, xml, dom, docx

I want to import in the data from the docx file to my CRM, I am using PHP DOMDocument::loadXML method for it, but I am not able to find a way through which I can import the Mathmatical formula and the images from the document file.
The Image of the word file is [image: word image]

The code through which I am trying to import is

```
    <?php
    $questionSheetRecord= readDocx("demo-stack.docx");
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($questionSheetRecord);
    echo "</pre>";

    function readDocx($filePath) {
        // Create new ZIP archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $dataFile = 'word/document.xml';
        // Open received archive file
        $returnArray=array();
        if (true === $zip->open($filePath)) {
            // If done, search for the data file in the archive
            if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
                // If found, read it to the string
                $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
                // Close archive file
                $zip->close();
                // Load XML from a string
                // Skip errors and warnings
                $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
                // Return data without XML formatting tags

                foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('p') as $child) {
                    $returnArray[]=  $child->nodeValue;
                }

                $text = $xml->saveXML();

                return $returnArray;
            }
            $zip->close();
        }
        // In case of failure return empty string
        return "";
    }
    ?>
```

`
Link of word file is 
[Word File to import data](https://github.com/aliabbas367/wordFile/blob/master/demo-stack.docx)
and link of code is [Code Link](https://github.com/aliabbas367/wordFile/blob/master/testing.php)

The output that I am getting while running this code is
[image: PHP Array fromat]  I want these a :  along with their post formula and picture.
I have gone through the other questions asked relating this issue but they are not the proper solution for this question.

> Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the "[update-v1.1.php](https://github.com/aliabbas367/wordFile)" and "[demo.docx](https://github.com/aliabbas367/wordFile)" file. Here you can get a code for extracting images from the word file, But the drawback in this code is that if you want to add any image in the word file then you have to add a tag "IMG1", here IMG has a post value of the sequence of the image, like if this is the first image in the word file then the tag will be IMG1 and if it is the sixth image then it will be IMG6. When you will run the code you will get the array which you can use in any why you want.

If anyone find any better solution please inform me here only.

Also I am searching a solution of exporting data into word with images at any specified place (means in-between text sentences, I want to insert 1 or more than one images).